# Is it ok to use custom headers on GET requests to send parameters?

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

I have a service that elaborates data sent to it in Headers. I use GET requests to send and receive back the elaborate data.

An example is:

```
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = "https://myendpoint.com";
  const method = "GET";

  Http.open(method, url, true);

  Http.setRequestHeader("Costum_Data_1", "my_costum_data_1");
  Http.setRequestHeader("Costum_Data_2", "my_costum_data_2");
```

I know that there's the `POST` method but, from a security point of view, sending data like that is ok?

Comment: You will get a preflight and you will need to handle option requests on the server

Comment: "OK" is largely a matter of opinion. It's *weird*. It loses many of the benefits of using GET. GET might not be the right choice of method in the first place.

Comment: If the backend is a C# controller it changes how the backend retrieves that value. It would have to be fetched from the Request.Headers["my_custum_data_1"]
Where something included in the body of the post could be used in the controller method parameters: [FromBody] List<string> fields for example

Comment: @TheEvilMetal — GET requests shouldn't (and, when sent via `XMLHttpRequest`, **can't**) have bodies.

Comment: @TheEvilMetal The backend is an edge function in JS. Yeah, I know how to handle it on the backend, I was just curious if that was the way to go in terms of security and best practice.